# Can I use both Mongoid and ActiveRecord ORMs in rails 4.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

My rails app now runs fine with these versions:

```
ruby 1.9.3
rails 3.2
mongoid 2.4
```

I rely on both ActiveRecord and Mongoid APIs -- ActiveRecord
wraps around a sqlite3 database, and Mongoid around a mongodb database.

I need to upgrade my app to ruby 2.0 and rails 4.x.  A quick search
shows that Mongoid APIs are not yet formally ported to ruby 2.0 / rails 4.x,
but some developers have figured out work-arounds.  However, the work-arounds
I browsed are for mongodb-only backends (ie, they rely on --skip-active-record
when generating the application).

Question:  can anyone say for sure whether using BOTH ActiveRecord
and Mongoid APIs will work under under ruby 2.0 and rails 4.x?

Comment: You're suggestion for using mongoid 4.x worked!  If you draft a formal answer, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in the middle of a Ruby-1.9.3/Rails-3.2/Mongoid-3 to Ruby-2.1.2/Rails-4.2/Mongoid-4 upgrade of a large application that uses both ActiveRecord and Mongoid. You'll want to use Mongoid-4 with Rails-4.x but I haven't encountered any problems specific to ActiveRecord and Mongoid (beyond the usual upgrading nonsense of course).

You might want to go from Mongoid-2 to Mongoid-3 before anything else. The Mongoid-3 and -4 interfaces are pretty much the same but I'm not so sure about Mongoid-2.

I'd also recommend moving to Ruby-2.x before touching Rails so a sequence like this might make things easier:

1. Upgrade Mongoid-2 to Mongoid-3.
2. Upgrade Ruby-1.9.3 to Ruby-2.x.
3. Upgrade Rails-3.2 and Mongoid-3 to Rails-4.0 and Mongoid-4.
4. Upgrade Rails-4.0 to Rails-4.1.
5. Upgrade Rails-4.1 to Rails-4.2.

Of course, you'll want to have a thorough test suite and you'll want to get everything passing before moving on to the next step.